# Thymeleaf code in Spring Boot attribute model

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

is it possible to sent thymeleaf code via attributeModel to View, to be treated like standard code?

I would like to load a piece of code(thymeleaf fragments) in different places only when it is needed.
But when I try this:

Spring Boot Controller:

```
model.addAttribute("fragment", "<th:block th:include=\"fragments/header :: body\"></th:block>");
```

View:

```
<div th:text="${fragment}"></div>
```

In WebBrowser as a TEXT I have:

```
<th:block th:include="fragments/header :: body"></th:block>
```

Can I force re-render? And how can I do that? But if it is not possible, what can I do in replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every thing that `th:text` parse, set to `innerHTML` and not rerendered.
You can set parameter in your `controller` and then check in `Thymeleaf` if that set, then include or replace your fragment. like this:

**Controller**

```
model.addAttribute("isFragmentBodyShow", true);
```

**View**

```
<th:block th:if="${isFragmentBodyShow}" th:include="fragments/header :: body"></th:block>
```

You can also send fragment name from `contoller` to `Thymeleaf` and use it in `th:include` for dynamic template include.